# Apache2 ASP MVC Razor view crashes when referencing PCL enum for dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, apache, mono

I am new to using ASP.net on ubuntu with mono, I have several websites working very well indeed using MVC5, though I recently migrated a project over and have found that forms referencing enums from a referenced PCL cause views to crash. Below is my EnumDropDownList call which works fine on a windows host.

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Type, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Type, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

When viewing this in the browser on the ubuntu host however I get the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The view found at '~/Views/portal/productgroup.cshtml' was not created.
```

Additional the stack trace is

```
     at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer) [0x00061] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00080] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0000b] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0004f] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0
```

Is there a way I need to reference the external assembly in my controller or my razor view? Is this a common issue or could there be something specific going on?

For reference the PCL holds some shared code for use between my site and a mobile app built using Xamarin. The PCL has the profile .NET framework 4.5 in addition to all of the Xamarin ones etc. The code is fully operational on windows and will work if I remove references to the enum stored in the PCL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and testing I have managed to solve my issue, I will explain the process now.

I switched to compiled MVCViews in my project configuration and noticed that they failed to compile due to not referencing System.Runtime in my web.config, I added this reference and then my views compiled, upon testing this locally it worked fine but failed with the same issue on mono.

Next I started to wonder whether mono had a version of System.Runtime so I installed the System.Runtime package from nuget, I noticed that upon building my project this was not added to my bin folder and was also missing from my project references even though nuget listed it as installed in visual studio.

Finally I just copied the System.Runtime.dll into my remote bin folder and this solved my problem. It seems that System.Runtime needs to be present any our bun folder if you rely on it.(Which you probably do!)

I hope this helps someone as I have spent MANY hours trying to find help on this!